# Number-guessing game with simple GUI

Tags: python, beginner, gui, number-guessing-game

This is my second program in Python. I am aware that globals are a bad idea, but that is what I have learned so far in my course.

Right now the program is doing what it's supposed to do, my only concern is that it might be too long for nothing. I'm asking you to help me figure out where I could make it simpler.

```
import simplegui
import random
import math

#Globals, random guess and player's remaining guesses

num_range = 100
remaining_guesses = 7

# New game, range from 0 - 100 by default
# after the according button is pressed
# Reset the remaining guesses to 7

def range100():
    global num_range
    global remaining_guesses
    remaining_guesses = 7
    print "New game. Range is from 0 to 100"
    print "Number of remaining guesses is %i" %(remaining_guesses)
    print ""
    num_range = random.randrange(0, 101)
    return num_range

# Set game to a range of 0 - 1000 
# after the according button is pressed
# Reset the remaining guesses to 10

def range1000():
    global num_range
    global remaining_guesses
    remaining_guesses = 10
    print "New game. Range is from 0 to 1000"
    print "Number of remaining guesses is %i" %(remaining_guesses)
    print ""
    num_range = random.randrange(0, 1001)
    return num_range

# Compare guess to random range
# Remove 1 to remaining guesses
# Display hint on the random range
# Restart the game if player is correct or out of guesses

def input_guess(guess):
    guess = float(guess)
    global remaining_guesses
    global num_range
    remaining_guesses -= 1
    print "Your guess was: %i" %(guess)
    print "Number of remaining guesses is %i" %(remaining_guesses)
    if (remaining_guesses == 0 and guess != num_range):
        print "The correct answer was %i" %(num_range)
        print "Let's try again!"
        print ""
        print ""
        range100()
    elif (remaining_guesses == 0 and guess == num_range):
        print "Correct!"
        print ""
        print ""
        range100() 
    elif guess > num_range:
        print "Try a lower number!"
    elif guess < num_range:
        print "Try a higher number!"
    else:
        print "Correct!"
        print ""
        print ""
        range100() 
    print ""
    return guess, remaining_guesses

# Create & start frame

f = simplegui.create_frame("Guess the number", 200, 200)

f.add_button("Range is [0, 100]", range100, 200)
f.add_button("Range is [0, 1000]", range1000, 200)
f.add_input('My label', input_guess, 50)
f.start()

# Start a new game

range100()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We have edited your question. For future reference, please read [ask].

Comment: Note that there are [two Python libraries named `simplegui`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16783864/1157100). The code in this question runs on [CodeSkulptor](http://www.codeskulptor.org), not the simplegui that acts as a wrapper for Tkinter.

Comment: @200_success oh i didn't know that, thank you

Comment: i completely deleted the function new_game(), i guess that's a good start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a function called `input_guess()`.  That function inputs the guess, compares the guess, and plays the entire game.  It should only input the guess.  I would create a function to run the program, one to input the number, and one to do the comparison and output prompts about being too large or small.  This way, only the function that plays the game needs to know the number of moves left.  Once the number is correctly guessed, that function just returns to its caller, who can call it again if the user wants to play again.  Also, try not to write functions this long.

As for your `range100()` and `range1000()` functions, I would combine those into one function like this:

```
def get_num(min, max):
    print "New game. Range is from " + min + " to " + max
    num = random.randrange(min, max + 1)
    return num
```

You can tell the user how many guesses they have left in the function that controls the game.

Finally, you should have the part of the program that always runs in an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.  This is for re-usability of your program, and you can read more about it here: [What does `if __name__ == “__main__”:` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).